# To make javascripts generic so that it can be applied to all images

Tags: javascript, html

I have written javascript functions to do zoomin and zoomout of an image via pinching.Now i want to generalize the below code so that i can add the javascript to the commonjavascript file.

```
    var scale = 1;
    var newScale;


    function saveChanges() {
           scale = newScale;
    }
    function getAngleAndScale(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        newScale = scale * e.scale;
        var tString = "scale(" + newScale + ")";
        document.getElementById("DocumentViewerImage").style.webkitTransform = tString;
    }
    function init(element) {
```

alert(element);
            document.getElementById("DocumentViewerImage").addEventListener("gesturechange", getAngleAndScale, false);
            document.getElementById("DocumentViewerImage").addEventListener("gestureend", saveChanges, false);
        }

In the above code i have hard coded the image id.I want to get the client id of the images and then pass it to javascript to make a call.How can i make it generic?How do i get client id and in which event shall i make a call?

I am using this code now:
 in the image tag: id="DocumentViewerImage" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 2%;" onload="init(this);" 
but in javascript if i say alert(element),i am getting as [objectHTMLImageElement].How do i get id of the image tag?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the ids via functions:

```
function getAngleAndScale(e, id) {
    e.preventDefault();
    newScale = scale * e.scale;
    var tString = "scale(" + newScale + ")";
    document.getElementById(id).style.webkitTransform = tString;
}
function init(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("gesturechange", getAngleAndScale, false);
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("gestureend", saveChanges, false);
}
```

Comment: yeah.but the thing is i am calling init function on   oninit event of body there how can i get the ids.I think i need to call init somewhere else but not getting where?

Answer (score 0):

Attach events to all the images which you wanted to zoomin and zoomout,like this:
    
    $('img#DocumentViewerImage').live("gesturechange", function() {

```
        getAngleAndScale(event);
});
$('img#DocumentViewerImage').live("gestureend", function() {

      saveChanges();
});
</script>
```

Javascripts:
    function saveChanges() {

```
scale = newScale;

}
function getAngleAndScale(e) {
var scale = 1;
var newScale;
var imgId = e.target.id;
// Don't zoom or rotate the whole screen
e.preventDefault();
// scale is an event property
newScale = scale * e.scale;
var tString = "scale(" + newScale + ")";
e.target.style.webkitTransform = tString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you also want to set the transform origin to the centerpoit of the pinch:
[Javascript, css: change transform origin to centerpoint of gesturechange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803876/javascript-css-change-transform-origin-to-centerpoint-of-gesturechange/22848488#22848488)

Hans